# How to output the subcommand execution process to the terminal

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to implement the following functions in python:
Restart the oracle database and execute some SQL statements
For example:
show parameter audit;
alter system set audit_trial=False
shutdown immediate
startup

Each part of the execution needs to be output to the terminal, rather than waiting for all the execution to be finished and then output to the terminal

I tried subprocess:

```
import subprocess
proc=subprocess.Popen("sqlplus  / as sysdba",shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,)
cmdlist=[
"show parameter audit; \n",
"alter system set audit_trial=False; \n",
"shutdown immediate \n",
"startup"
]
for cmds in cmdlist:
  proc.stdin.write(cmds)
  proc.stdin.flush()
  for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline,'')
    print line
proc.stdin.close()
```

Deadlock occurs in the following code

```
  for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline,'')
    print line
```